# How to get "#" from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I use [xml2json](https://github.com/sparkbuzz/jquery-xml2json/blob/master/README.markdown) change XML to JSON.
But the result of JSON is very strange like this,
[image]

```
console.log(xml);
var json = $.xml2json(xml);
console.log(json);
```

But when I `console.log(json.#document)`, it's become undefined.

How could I get the `#document` from JSON??

Comment: what about `console.log(json['#document'])` ?

Comment: oh, Yes!! I didn't think of it before, thanks a lot!!